# Bootstrap horizontal formatting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on making a page to understand Bootstrap formatting better, but am having a very difficult time figuring out how to use the columns in association with the other types of classes. I want to create a window to hold a potential Javascript game. Next to it, I want to put a rectangular area for scores to be displayed. The thing that I would appreciate help with is understanding how to format the divs in HTML and Bootstrap to create the game area and scoreboard area. Here is a snippet of code that I was messing around with to space it, but I can't tell what to do with it.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-8">Here is a column</div>
<div class="well">Game container</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">Here is another column</div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
```

This link has an image of the general layout I am aiming for. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCeFA.jpg

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure for your task.And you can customize(width of the column) it according to your requirement.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">Here is a column</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Javascript container</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Score column</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This look like the layout, right?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1 " style="background-color: aliceblue;">Here is a column</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color: aliceblue;" >Here is another column</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each row in bootstrap can have upto 12 columns and xs, sm, md, lg specifies how many columns it will take in extra-small, small, medium and large devices respectively.

So if you write

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

this will create your first row with 1 column taking all space in all devices greater than and equal to an extra small device (-xs).

And if you write

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div
```

this will create your second row with column taking space equal to 8 columns and second column taking space equal to 4 columns. Notice sum 12 (8+4).And this will take this space in all devices greater than and equal to a medium device (-md) and in all smaller devies (-sm, -xs) it will break into 1 column taking space of 12 columns like your first row.

And third row can be created similar to first row.
I hope this helps, if you have any other queries you can comment on this :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the sample two column layout from the image you provided.

```css
.custom {
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="custom">
        1st column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="custom">
        2nd column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```